# How do I bring a manually created json array in fire base realtime database and save it as a variable in my react native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Like the title suggests, I've manually uploaded a json array to my fire base. There is a variable called 'entirelog' that currently stores a local json array that I used as this.state.entirelog through out my entire code. But, I'm trying to now pull it from firebase and simply save the pulled json array as this.state.entirelog using setState, so I don't have to change the latter bottom of my code. How do I accomplish this?

```
async componentDidMount() {

    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 
      authDomain: 
      databaseURL: 
      projectId:
      storageBucket: 
      messagingSenderId: 
      appId:
      measurementId:
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    firebase.database().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      this.setState({
        entirelog: snapshot.val()
      });
    });
```

this is what my entire log is added as locally (which I wanted to make it empty eventually and bring from firebase)

```
this.state = {
      isReady: false,
      activeSections: [0],
      currentdate: '',
      displaydate: '',
      indexofdate: 0,
      entirelog : [{
        "date": "22-5-2020",
        "meals": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "egg",
            "imageurl": "something",
            "protein": 1,
            "carbohydrate": 2,
            "fat": 3
          },
//continues from here
```

The attached image is what my array looks like in firebase that I added manually
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the state of the entirelog as an empty array at the start -

```
this.state = {
      entirelog : []
    }
```

and at componentDidMount() method  -

```
componentDidMount(){
this.setState({
        entirelog: snapshot.val()
      });
}
```

While reading it in render method you can set a condition if the data exist or not -

```
{
   this.state.entirelog && this.state.entirelog.length ? <YourComponent> :null}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am currently getting an erro message [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.default.database().once is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.database().once('value')', '_firebase.default.database().once' is undefined)] is my function for getting the database correct?